# When we can consider a body to be point sized?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

In motion we idealize big object to be point sized. But we don't do it all the times. I am having some confusion on it. Please tell when we consider objects to be point sized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost every case, we choose to model an object as a point because **we don't care about the object's internal structure** for the calculation we're trying to make. This can have several causes; for example:

- The effect of the object's internal structure may simply be too small to be detectable in the results;
- The desired precision of the calculation may be loose enough that we can choose to ignore the effect of the object's internal structure without loss of accuracy;
- The cost in additional complexity of treating the object's internal structure is not worth the increase in accuracy of the result;

and so on.

There is one class of exceptions: many of the fundamental particles (for example, the electron) have no currently-measurable internal structure. They are, to our current instruments, indistinguishable from being point particles. So in this particular case, we model them as point particles because, as far as we know, they *really are* point particles.

Answer (score -1):

When we are dealing with their mass.  For example, Newton's law of gravity deals with two objects as the distance between their masses.  The "point" is the center of mass of the object which is just a theoretical mathematical point.  Remember that there is a difference between total mass and mass density.  When you observe an object in space you are looking at its mass density.  A marshmallow deep under water, or at sea level, or in the vacuum of space all have the same mass but quite different mass densities.  The question is still open weather an object can be compressed all the way down to a single point (singularity) with known simultaneous location and momentum. Relativity says yes but theory fails at singularity, quantum theory says no.  The only point like objects are singularities at the center of black holes or the big bang singularity but these are only theoretical.  Fundamental quantum particles are considered to be point like but must be described by probability wave function except at moment of interaction when wave collapses and they behave as point like particles.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  I was asking about idealizing of object to point mass when we study kinematics.